# Store sync: Many deletions, some failed

Tags: extjs

I have a store in which the user could delete multiple records with a single `destroy` operation.

Now, a few of these records are locked in the database (because someone else is working on them), and thus cannot be deleted. How can the server tell the frontend that the deletion of records with Id a, b, c was successful, but that records with Id x, y, z could not be deleted and should be moved back into the store and displayed in the grid?

The ExtJS store should know after the `sync()` which records were really deleted server-side, and which weren't.

Comment: Is your store ajax driven ? Means each time ajax request is called to update itself ?

Comment: @Alexander in the sync you can pass the failure callback with params 
```store.sync({
        callback: function (records, operation, success) {
        },
        success: function (batch, options) {
        },
        failure: function (batch, options) {

        }
    });``` I am not sure but maybe there is something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no straightforward solution to this problem. I have opted for the following workaround:

The records now have an "IsDeleted" flag that is set to `false` by default:

```
fields:[{
    ...
},{
    name: 'IsDeleted'
    type: 'bool',
    defaultValue: false
```

The store has a filter that hides entries where the flag is set to `true`:

```
filters:[{
    property:'IsDeleted',
    value:false
}]
```

When the user opts to delete, I don't `remove` entries from the store, instead I set the `IsDeleted` flag to `true` on these entries. The filter makes the user think that the entry has been deleted.

When the store syncs, it does an `update` operation, not a `destroy` operation. So the update endpoint of the API then has to delete all entries where `IsDeleted` is transmitted as `true`. If it can't delete an entry from the database, the corresponding json as returned to the client gets `IsDeleted` set to `false`, so that the frontend gets to know that the deletion of that entry failed.