# Set grid id dynamicly from DB extjs6

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a grid.
This grid gets data from postgres table.
This table uses 4 users.
The problem is if user B create and a row in a table with id:5, user A would not know it. So when user A create a row he should know what is the last id or create an a row and get back rows id.

When i press "Add" button in a grid , extjs send "create" command to server, server retruns "success: true" and number of "id" new created row  in a postgres table.
Id like to show and use this 'id' in my grid.
For example if i add a row, and get "id: 19' from server, i have to create 19 row in and grid. When i`d like to edit this row, etxjs have to send to server update with 'id:19'.
How to make it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/extjs/ext-6.2.0/build/classic/theme-classic/resources/theme-classic-all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/extjs/ext-6.2.0/build/ext.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/extjs/ext-6.2.0/build/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.require(['Ext.data.*', 'Ext.grid.*']);


        // Создаем model
        Ext.define('Users', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            idProperty: 'id',
            //idProperty: 'id',
            fields: [{
                    name: 'id',
                    type: 'int',
                    mapping: 'id'
                },
                //{name: 'date', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'}
                // {
                //     name: 'time',
                //     type: 'date',
                //     dateFormat: 'H:i'
                // },
            ]
        });

        // var occupationStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        //     fields: ['time'],
        //     data: [{
        //             time: 'CEO'
        //         },
        //         {
        //             time: 'Vicepresident'
        //         },
        //         {
        //             time: 'Marketing manager'
        //         },
        //     ]
        // });

        Ext.onReady(function() {
            // Создаем store
            var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    autoLoad: true,
                    autoSync: true,
                    model: 'Users',
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url: 's.rakov.php',
                        api: {
                            create: 's.rakov.php?action=create',
                            read: 's.rakov.php?action=read',
                            update: 's.rakov.php?action=update',
                            destroy: 's.rakov.php?action=delete'
                        },
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            rootProperty: 'data'
                        },
                        writer: {
                            type: 'json',
                            encode: true,
                            rootProperty: 'dataUpdate',
                            allowSingle: false,
                            writeAllFields: true,
                            //root:'records'
                        },
                        actionMethods: {
                            create: 'GET',
                            read: 'GET',
                            update: 'GET',
                            destroy: 'GET'

                        }
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        write: function(store, operation) {
                            var record = operation.getRecords()[0],
                                name = Ext.String.capitalize(operation.action),
                                verb;


                            if (name == 'Destroy') {
                                verb = 'Destroyed';
                            } else {
                                verb = name + 'd';
                            }
                            //Ext.example.msg(name, Ext.String.format("{0} user: {1}", verb, record.getId()));

                        }
                    }
                }


            );

            var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                renderTo: document.body,
                //plugins: [rowEditing],
                // Редактирование
                plugins: {
                    ptype: 'cellediting',
                    clicksToEdit: 1
                },
                listeners: {
                    edit: function() {

                    }
                },
                width: '99,3%',
                height: 330,
                frame: true,
                title: 'Users',
                store: store,
                iconCls: 'icon-user',
                columns: [{
                        text: 'id',
                        width: '2%',
                        sortable: true,
                        dataIndex: 'id',
                        renderer: function(v, meta, rec) {
                            return rec.phantom ? '' : v;
                        }
                    },
                     {
                        header: 'Задача',
                        width: '30%',
                        // sortable: true,
                        dataIndex: 'task',
                        editor: {
                            completeOnEnter: false,
                            field: {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                //name: 'timeStart1',
                                //fieldLabel: 'Time In',
                                anchor: '100%',
                                allowBlank: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Время начала',
                        width: 120,
                        // sortable: true,
                        dataIndex: 'time_start',
                        //format: 'H:i',
                        // Нужно для верного отображеия времени после редактирования в таблице
                        renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('H:i'),
                        editor: {
                            completeOnEnter: false,
                            field: {
                                xtype: 'timefield',
                                format: 'H:i',
                                //name: 'timeStart1',
                                //fieldLabel: 'Time In',
                                minValue: '8:00',
                                maxValue: '20:00',
                                increment: 30,
                                anchor: '100%',
                                //allowBlank: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Результат',
                        width: '30%',
                        // sortable: true,
                        dataIndex: 'task_result',
                        editor: {
                            completeOnEnter: false,
                            field: {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                //name: 'timeStart1',
                                //fieldLabel: 'Time In',
                                //anchor: '100%',
                                allowBlank: false
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    {
                        header: 'Время конца',
                        width: 120,
                        // sortable: true,
                        dataIndex: 'time_end',
                        //format: 'H:i',
                        // Нужно для верного отображеия времени после редактирования в таблице
                        renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('H:i'),
                        editor: {
                            completeOnEnter: false,
                            field: {
                                xtype: 'timefield',
                                format: 'H:i',
                                //name: 'timeStart1',
                                //fieldLabel: 'Time In',
                                minValue: '8:00',
                                maxValue: '20:00',
                                increment: 30,
                                anchor: '100%',
                                allowBlank: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Дата',
                        width: 70,
                        // sortable: true,
                        dataIndex: 'date',
                        renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y'),
                        editor: {
                            completeOnEnter: false,
                            field: {
                                xtype: 'datefield',
                                dateFormat: 'd/m/Y',
                                allowBlank: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Длительность',
                        width: 60,
                        // sortable: true,
                        dataIndex: 'time_duration'
                    },

                    // {
     //                    header: 'Тип задачи',
     //                    width: 120,
     //                    // sortable: true,
     //                    dataIndex: 'task_type',
     //                    editor: {
     //                        completeOnEnter: false,
     //                        field: {
     //                            xtype: 'combobox',
     //                            //name: 'timeStart1',
     //                            //fieldLabel: 'Time In',
     //                            anchor: '100%',
     //                            allowBlank: false
     //                        }
     //                    }
     //                }

                ],
                dockedItems: [{
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    items: [{
                        text: 'Add',
                        iconCls: 'icon-add',
                        handler: function() {
                            // Создаем новую задачу
                            // Для корректной работы с БД нужно задать ID новой строки, равной +1 от последней ID из таблицы.
                            var rec = new Users();
                            //console.log (x);("rec data= " + rec.id + " -- " + rec.data.id);
                            var idArr = grid.store.data.items;
                            var idValue = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < idArr.length; i++) {
                                idValue.push(idArr[i].id);
                            }
                            idValue.sort(function(a, b) {
                                return a - b;
                            });
                            var maxId = idValue[idValue.length - 1];
                            console.log(maxId);
                            //rec.id = maxId + 1;
                            //rec.data.id = maxId + 1;

                            rec.date = Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y-m-d\\T00:00:00');
                            rec.data.date = Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y-m-d\\T00:00:00');

                            rec.time_start = Ext.Date.format(new Date(), '2008-01-01\\TH:i:s');
                            rec.data.time_start = Ext.Date.format(new Date(), '2008-01-01\\TH:i:s');
                            store.insert(0, rec);
                            //store.add(rac);
                            //grid.getView().refresh();
                            // rowEditing.startEdit(rec, 0);
                        }
                    }, '-', {
                        itemId: 'delete',
                        text: 'Delete',
                        iconCls: 'icon-delete',
                        disabled: false,
                        handler: function() {
                            var selection = grid.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                            if (confirm('Вы действительно хотите удалить задачу №' + selection.id + " ?")) {
                                // Удлаяем      
                                if (selection) {
                                    store.remove(selection);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="gridDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the new id to the client in the update response.

I have made a fiddle for you: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/226o

In short, when the client sends to the server the create request with the body e.g.

```
{"updateData":[{"task":"Test", "id":"ext-task-46"},{"task":"Test 2", id: "ext-task-47"}]}
```

(`updateData` being your writer's `rootProperty`), the server has to answer with

```
{"success":true,"data":[{"task:"Test","id":5},{"task:"Test 2","id":6}]
```

or, shorter, with

```
{"success":true,"data":[{"id":5},{"id":6}]
```

(`data` being your reader's `rootProperty`). The matching between the submitted and the returned records for the id update is by position; and all other fields can be updated as well.

The server can thus return to the client any changes that have been enforced by the server on the submitted records; [except for the fact that certain records could not be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652956/store-sync-many-deletions-some-failed).